# Torsion-free sheaves over nodal curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be an irreducible nodal curve (over $\mathbb{C}$) with exactly one node, say at $x$. Let $F$ be a torsion-free, rank $n$ sheaf on $X$. We know that $F_x \cong \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^{\oplus n-a} \oplus m_x^{\oplus a}$ for some integer $a$, where $m_x$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. Using Chapter II. Lemma $2.3$ of [Special divisors and vector bundles](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.tmj/1178228323) by S. Narasimhan, we know that if the normalisation of $X$ is rational, then there exists a rank $n$ locally free sheaf $E$ on $X$ containing $F$ such that $E/F$ is supported at $x$ and is isomorphic to $k(x)^{\oplus a}$. This result has been cited in $(2.7)$ of [Torsion-free sheaves on nodal curves and triples](http://www.mat.ufmg.br/~dan/artigos/torsion-free.pdf)
by H. Lange and others. However, the curve in this case need not normalise to a rational curve.

My question is: Does the proof of Lemma II$.2.3$ in the paper of Narasimahan, generalise to torsion-free sheaves on *any nodal curve* with exactly one node? Is there a reference for this more general result?

Comment: Since étale locally every node looks the same, can't you just take an étale neighbourhood of $x$, use the result of Narasimhan to obtain such an $E$ and then glue it back using the descent theory for fpqc morphisms and coherent sheaves?